# Flutter stuck on 'flutter' command - no output to console and it doesn't ever finish

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, flutter

I started following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLSG_Wh_YWc) tutorial about Flutter, and I followed each step until the installation of Flutter on windows, even added flutter to PATH.

Now, once I try to execute `flutter` in CMD / Powershell (I work on Windows 10), it gives no output.
It seems to recognize the command, but it doesn't give further output for a very long time, the console just remains empty.

Has anyone encountered that problem before and knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: just `flutter`? nothing more? what you see if you run `flutter --version` or `flutter doctor`?

Comment: @pskink still nothing on both

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Comment: @pskink Yes but please take a look in the tutorial at 36:17... he makes it work in a normal cmd not just the special console... for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @pskink Nope. doesn't work still.

Comment: you followed https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows and it does not work? so remove **everything** you installed so far and try again - this is the official way and 1000s of people got it working

Comment: @pskink The problem was that I installed it in C:/Program Files, the guy in the course didn't mention anything about that but in the link you sent they did. Thank you for your help!

Comment: sure, you're welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I installed it in C:/Program Files, the guy in the course didn't mention anything about that but in the link you sent they did.

Here's the key takeaway.

[image]

Installing flutter in places that requires elevated privileges (e.g. `C:\Program Files\` won't work.

Thank you @pskink for the link.

Answer (score 1):

it takes a long time, just wait. or you input flutter  --verbose, it will output infomation to console.

Comment: that is a very slippery answer. In my case, this kind of hangups are usually caused by a slow network which would not be clearly indicated by the "verbose" flag

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is still in early development (version 1.20 at this point) and things seem to break (occasionally)

I just uninstalled and reinstalled flutter, which got it working again....

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04 I installed flutter using snap. When there is a new release, it downloads almost 500M of files to refresh, and the whole time there is no output (even when I use --verbose flag). I had to use strace to find that a file is being downloaded.

> sudo strace -f -t -e trace=file flutter

The output:

> [pid  7377] 11:44:20 openat(AT_FDCWD, "latest_stable.tar.xz", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 6
>
> 0  515M    0 2206k    0     0   321k      0  0:27:22  0:00:06  0:27:16  375k^Cstrace: Process 7377 detached

Answer (score -1):

Official flutter recommendations tell do not to install flutter in places like C:\Program Files\ which could require elevated privileges.

But in my case, it was a solution cuz in other places flutter just killed the terminal.
So, I placed it in C:\Program Files\ and ran the terminal as administrator, it's the only solution I found.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).